Using Power Automate for specific Excel - Planner interactions
I've recently begun learning to use Power Automate to streamline repetitive tasks in my work. Although it's quite different from most computational approaches I'm used to, I haven't been able to get it to respond well for this specific example.

Take a specified Excel Workbook (Sharepoint or OneDrive)

Detect any changes and list the rows of a table Table X when this happens.
The table has a format something like this (formatting to indicate similar values) :





Column A
Column B
...
Date Column
ID Column




Aaaaa
Bbbbb
...
2025-06-03
99999


Ccccc
Ddddd
...
2025-06-03
99999


Lorem
Ipsum
...
2025-04-02
12345


quick
brown
...
2025-07-09
31415


Dolor
Amet
...
2025-04-02
12345


fox
jumps
...
2025-07-09
31415




List all rows with a unique ID Column value (take first) and search for this value in the task titles of a Microsoft Planner plan

Filter by a given Bucket 'Bucket A'



An example task title looks like : 99999 Other text 111111

Update the relevant tasks (that include the ID Column) with the corresponding Date Column as their due date.

At the moment, I've tried a few different approaches with different triggers, but my flow seems to be tripping up around the Apply to Each loop.

Sorry but too hard to help without showing us the flow itself.  Also, what does "tripping up" mean?  Errors?  Unexpected/bad behaviour?

Thanks for your reply, @Skin. I've been experiencing a few different errors at that point and tried debugging but I don't know where to go from here. See attached screenshots



https://imgur.com/Jw25C6e
https://imgur.com/r4zpkDI
